# Unique Property in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using alfresco 4.2e,I would like to add unique property for particular type of document say type1 in whole repository of alfresco.

a document has below properties called

Name

UIV(Unique Identification Value) ==> I want this property to be unique in whole repository

Owner

Newly added property should not repeat its value in whole repository.I know i can add this using record management ,implementing validation handler in share or implementing NodePolicy.But above both implementation will not work in my case due to some other configuration.Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm probably missing the point, but wouldn't the already existing nodeRef suit your needs? it's a unique property value for each element in the repository.

Comment: I would like to save value which user enters,and this value should be understandable,like name which we are giving to document.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the Behavior you can search like this

```
String query = "SELECT SCORE() FROM cmis:document WHERE someprefix:UIV = " + value;

ResultSet rs = searchService.query(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE, SearchService.LANGUAGE_CMIS_ALFRESCO, query);

if (rs.getNumberFound() > 0)
{
 // duplicates
}
```

Comment: give a little more explanation as why you are suggesting this and why it is suitable.

Comment: It's a way to check the property is unique. Well another way could be, to set the property based on a timestamp for example.

Comment: I know i can do this with behaviour,validation handler in share and record management.I would like to know other way.like defining some sort thing in xml or some other way.

Comment: Is a Rule can be an option? You might still need to create a custom action. But then you can configure the Rule from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco does not support unique property values out of the box (only child associations). Have a look at https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide . The only reasonable approach to ensure unique property values that I can think of are (as you mention) based on NodeServicePolicies and behaviors.